# how to implement "remember me" in angular 2,in login page

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I tried to implement remember me in angular 2, like using documnent.cookie and ngx-cookie .but not working.can anyone help me by referring some example to try?

Comment: If you were to share your code, or bits of your code, people would be better placed to try and help you resolve your issue.

Comment: You may wanna take a look at JWT

Comment: I need to implement in the login page.just I need to store email id and password in a cookie.https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie,tried this one

Comment: @GurV: `JWT` needs to be generated in back-end not in front-end

Comment: Are You use back-end? If yes, You can implement `remember me` using `JWT`, and You can store generated `JWT token` in `local storage`

Comment: @Salim Yes. Exactly.

Comment: client side I am doing.not able to understand JWT.how to implement?  trying from two days

Comment: in angular 2, saving in local storage or in a cookie, but not showing in the dropdown.can anyone help to implement?.struggling like hell.I don't know how to use JWT in client-side also.

Answer (score 0):

You can store userName and Password in local storage and ngOnInit() assign it to respectively if it is available.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" name="username"
                 minlength="4" required>
<input class="form-control" type="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" name="password" required>
```

In Component

```
ngOnInit() {if(this.storage.retrieve('userAuth')) {
  this.model = this.storage.retrieve('userAuth');
}}

//Save user Credentials when Remember me checked.
rememberMe() : void {
this.storage.store('userAuth', this.model);}
```